# PHP rest wrapper for api endpoint with query

Tags: php, rest, api, endpoint

I have an api that I can test at it's current endpoint with a query (this is for a search with autocomplete) like so:

```
.../search/autocomplete?query=product123
```

And this returns the results expected. However, this is the first time I've made a php rest/wrapper for an api using a query instead of fields.

My question is, using a hard coded test variable below, How should I properly pass this into the function and properly query the endpoint?

This is a test but basically it's going to be used as someone types into a search box and passes from there, so same idea.

Am I on the right track with this?

```
$testVariable = "product123"

public function getSearch($testVariable)
    {
        return $this->get("/search/autocomplete?query={$testVariable}");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Just because you named the variables the same doesn't mean they are the same.  They exist in different scopes, you'd still have to call that function and pass in your variable.

Comment: I just named them the same in this example for the sake of clarity. I"m just making sure if I pass in a variable to represent that product name, that I'm properly calling it in the return as {$testVariable} or if I should do that differently

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're asking.  Are you asking if "{$testVariable}" will evaluate the variable?  If so, did you think to just test it?  `echo "/search/autocomplete?query={$testVariable}"`

Comment: You are missing at least a [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) call. Other than that I also don't quite get what you're asking.